# compile MobileVLC for iOS

Tags: ios

I am compiling

**

**ld: library not found for -lMobileVLCKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

**

I can't compile the MoblieVLCKit.a ,how to solve this?

Comment: Command /Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1

Comment: /Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /VLC/VLC/projects/macosx/framework/../../../install-ios-OS/lib/libvlc.a (No such file or directory)
/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /VLC/VLC/projects/macosx/framework/../../../install-ios-OS/lib/libvlccore.a (No such file or directory)